# piping subprocess output to stdin in python not working

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to check if a file is formatted correctly

```
command_process = subprocess.Popen('black -q
    file_utils.py'.split(' '), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

subprocess.run(['diff', '-q', 'file_utils.py'], 
    stdin=command_process.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
```

I get the following error with above commands

```
diff: missing operand after `file_utils.py'
diff: Try `diff --help' for more information.
CompletedProcess(args=['diff', '-q', 'file_utils.py'], returncode=2, stdout='')
```

Comment: Don't use `str.split`; it doesn't follow shell syntax rules. Construct the list manually, or use `shlex.split`.

Answer (score 0):

`diff` needs to be told to read from standard input.

```
subprocess.run(['diff', '-q', 'file_utils.py', '-'], 
stdin=command_process.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
```

or

```
subprocess.run(['diff', '-q', '-', 'file_utils.py'], 
stdin=command_process.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
```

depending on the order you want.